# How does Twilio segment long messages containing urls?

Tags: sms, twilio, twilio-api

Let's consider a string M which contains some words and a url that puts the final message length at 1000 characters (including the characters in the url).

I know Twilio auto-segments messages > 160 chars:
Ref. [article](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181508-Does-Twilio-support-concatenated-SMS-messages-or-messages-over-160-characters-).

> Twilio will auto-segment long messages with a special header, which mobile carriers can use to reassemble the segments on the destination handset. Thus, concatenated SMS can appear as one single message on the receiving device.

My question is will it segment the message in a way that breaks the url into multiple parts or does Twilio account for urls in the message during the segmentation?

Example: The message gets segmented at a point such that the url in the message say `https://www.example.com/some-url`, gets broken across two segments say - `https://www.exampl`(in one segment) and `e.com/some-url` (in another segment).